# Python script for an automatic map composer have a bug with refresh

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

I have an issue with my script. I would like to show a part of map centered on selected features with a template. The script open the print composer but it don't refresh correctly the map, it's blank. I followed [this tutorial](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/). In the map element of the composer, scale is set to 0.0000000000, min X max X min Y max Y are set to 0.000.
here the concerned part of my script:

```
                self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
                self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(1000)

                canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
                myFile = os.path.join('C:\Users\mypath\\', 'template.qpt')
                myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
                myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
                myTemplateFile.close()
                myDocument = QDomDocument()
                myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
                newcomp = iface.createNewComposer()
                newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

                composition = newcomp.composition()
                map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('map')
                map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)

                map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())

                composition.refreshItems()
```

My Qgis version is 2.16.3. And the Python console of Qgis don't show any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change my code and it work now !

```
                self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
                self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(1000)


                canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
                myFile = os.path.join('C:\Users\mypath\\', 'template.qpt')
                myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
                myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
                myTemplateFile.close()
                myDocument = QDomDocument()
                myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
                newcomp = iface.createNewComposer()
                newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

                composition = newcomp.composition()
                map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('map')
                map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)

                map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())                    

                composition.refreshItems()
```